# vpnc resolvconf breaks DNS records

Tags: gnome, networkmanager, vpnc

I have Ubuntu 11.04, Network Manager + vpnc + resolvconf. I have some VPN and wired connections configured in Network Manager.

Whenever I connect to the VPN my `/etc/resolv.conf` gets populated with the VPN's DNS nameservers in front of the eth0 record. However after five minutes or so, the eth0 connection's nameserver becomes first in the list.

How can I disable this kind of behavior?

Comment: Did you solve this problem yet? I have an answer below that might work.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to your vpnc config (if using the command line, edit it through the gui for Network Manager)

```
DNSUpdate no
```

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1623624

And manually add your dns entries